Programmatic pagination in richtextbox with pictures and long strings
I have written a program (vb.net) to inventory my stuff. I did this for insurance purposes. My program lets me create categories (like “floor model power tools” or “bench tools”,etc.) and then enter items into each category with some details (where did I buy it, model, serial number, URL of the item or a replacement), what it would cost to replace it, etc. I am also able to associate one or more pictures of the item with it and each picture can include a URL also. There is no limit other than my time to how many pictures I can attach. My program also is able to tell me using coordinates on a specified picture where in my home the item is located. I have a lot of stuff and a lot of categories and a lot of pictures. I can run reports of my categories which collect all of the information about all of the items in each category into an RTF file. I am able to split the files (during the run of the report) into multiple files when they get too big. Almost everything works perfectly. I have run into one thing that I am not able to get to work PERFECTLY. I can live with what I have if I have to, but if I can get it the last mile I would like to do so.
When my program is reporting a category, it also pastes the pictures attached to each record into the document. I feel this is an important part of the insurance aspect...proving that I have what I say I have. My program does this quite well. I included the code I use to do this with this post. What I have not been able to do absolutely reliably is to count the lines on pages because I have not been able to figure out the best way to translate the images into a number of lines. I have my code also with this post. The literals used come from my research and some “educated” guessing. The line that is not commented out is the one I have found to be the closest to what I need but I don’t know if that is because it is close or if it is just dumb luck. I am quite overwhelmed and I’m hoping someone here can get me the last mile or just pointed in the right direction. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thx
e.g.bell
ImageFactory
A class I created to handle image functions my program uses.
DoReportLine
puts a string in a rich text box setting the font before and after and, if specified a carriage return after it (Defaults to a carriage return if I don’t specify)
HandleLinesAndPages
Increments the line counter by specified amount. If it exceeds a specified max per page, the page counter is incremented
‘– Get picture in clipboard and paste it into richtextbox
ImageFactory = New clsImageFactory(Me.LblErrorMessage)
ImageFactory.CopyImageToClipboard(Directory_Server.ShopAndCraftsPictureFilePath _
                                  & "\" _
                                  & picture.ImageName)

HandleLinesAndPages(LineCount, ImageFactory.GetPrintLinesOfImage("W", SC_BoldFont), Pages)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DoReportLine(m_Tab_2, SC_RegularFont, SC_RegularFont)

Me.rtfReport.Paste()

DoReportLine(String.Empty, SC_ConsolasBold, SC_RegularFont, True)
HandleLinesAndPages(LineCount, 1, Pages)

DoReportLine(m_Tab_1 & "Picture".PadRight(ReportPad, ".") _
             & picture.ImageName, SC_ConsolasBold, SC_RegularFont)
HandleLinesAndPages(LineCount, 1, Pages)   





‘– From ImageFactory class
Public Function GetPrintLinesOfImage(ByVal Text As String, ByVal fonttomeasure As Font) As Single

Dim LineCount As Single = 0.0

Dim sf As SizeF = GetStringSize(Text, fonttomeasure)

If sf.Height > 0 AndAlso
   m_ImageHeight > 0 Then

   Dim ImageToInches = m_ImagePhysicalDimensions.Height * 0.0006944444
   Dim CharToInches = sf.Height * 0.013888888888889

   'LineCount = (m_ImageHeight * 0.75) / (sf.Height * fonttomeasure.SizeInPoints)

   LineCount = (m_ImagePhysicalDimensions.Height * 0.75) / (sf.Height * fonttomeasure.SizeInPoints)

   '''''LineCount = (m_ImagePhysicalDimensions.Height) / (sf.Height * fonttomeasure.SizeInPoints)

   '-- convert twips to pixels to points
   'LineCount = ((m_ImagePhysicalDimensions.Height * 0.66667) * 0.75) / (sf.Height * fonttomeasure.SizeInPoints)

End If

Return LineCount

End Function


‘- Count lines in RTF added. Account for lines that are longer than the allowable columns
‘- and increment line count rounding up to the next integer if longer than one line

If picture.URL.Length < c_MaxColumnsPerPage Then
   HandleLinesAndPages(LineCount, 1, Pages)
Else
   HandleLinesAndPages(LineCount, (MaxColumnsPerPage / picture.URL.Length) + 0.999, Pages)
End If





‘– Code to get size of string
Public Function GetStringSize(ByVal Text As String, ByVal fontToMeasure As Font) As SizeF

      Dim sizeOfString As New SizeF
      Dim f As New Form
      f.Font = fontToMeasure

      Dim ftmheight As Single = fontToMeasure.GetHeight

      Dim g As Graphics = f.CreateGraphics

      sizeOfString = g.MeasureString(Text, fontToMeasure)

      Return sizeOfString

   End Function

